# What are the values of $a$ and $b$ so that $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_9$ is isomorphic with $\Bbb Z_a\times\Bbb Z_b$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

I'm studying group theory, (at basic level), and i got this problem:

Find all pairs $(a,b)$ of positive integers so that:

$$\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3\times\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_9$$

is isomorphic with

$$\Bbb Z_a\times\Bbb Z_b.$$

I know that $\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ is cyclic, so is isomorphic with $\Bbb Z_6$, and so $\Bbb Z_9\times\Bbb Z_4$ with $\Bbb Z_{36}$ , but in this way I just found two isomorphisms, $\Bbb Z_6\times\Bbb Z_{36}$ and $\Bbb Z_{18}\times\Bbb Z_{12}$. Is it right?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's right. It follows from coprimality and the [Chinese remainder theorem.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Chinese%20remainder,the%20divisors%20are%20pairwise%20coprime.)

Comment: I think you should provide a link for the Chinese Remainder Theorem to make this answer complete.

Comment: That's a good idea, @Mr.GandalfSauron. Thank you. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Just a question about formating . Do you know how to link a page such that it opens to the spot where the relevant info is. For example in this link, the exact reference is in the "statements" portion. I do not know how to format links like that. Do you have any idea?

Comment: I'm afraid not, @Mr.GandalfSauron.

Comment: Ah well....we'll have to live with it I guess

Comment: Thank you!! I really appreciate this.

Comment: You're welcome, @PietroSileci. After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).